# Golang UPDATE column with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, go

Let's say I have a table `employments` and a struct `Employment`

```
type Employment struct {
    ID              int     `json:"id"`
    Created_at      string  `json:"created_at"`
    Updated_at      string  `json:"updated_at"`
    Education       string  `json:"education"`
    Job             string  `json:"job"`
    Position        string  `json:"position"`
    Business_phone  string  `json:"business_phone"`
    Next_payday     string  `json:"next_payday"`
    Employment_type int     `json:"employment_type"`
    Income          float64 `json:"income"`
    Additional      float64 `json:"additional"`
}
```

User can update their `employment`, the problem is I don't know which fields user want to update.

So that, I decided to range over input struct to get `non nil fields` to generate query string, some thing like `UPDATE employments SET position=$1, income=$2 WHERE id=$3`

This is what I got this time

```
func FlexibleUpdate(table_name string, str interface{}, cond string, ret string) string {

    query := "UPDATE " + table_name + " SET "
    j := 0
    m := structs.Map(str)

    for i := range m {
        if m[i] != "" && m[i] != 0 && m[i] != 0.0 && {
            j++
            query = query + strings.ToLower(i) + "=$" + strconv.Itoa(j) + ","
        }
    }
    j++

    // adding conditions
    if cond != "" {
        query = query[:len(query)-1] + " WHERE " + cond + "=$" + strconv.Itoa(j)
    }

    // return values
    if ret != "" {
        query = query + " RETURNING " + ret
    }

    return query
}
```

I don't know how to assign input values to `$1, $2, ...` to execute query

```
database.DB.QueryRow(query_string, value_1, value_2, ...)
```

Let me know if you have any idea or another way to resolve it.

Comment: SQL injection much? This is very vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. At least as far as what code you've posted.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean @RayfenWindspear ?

Comment: Assuming this comes from a web form of some type. Manage on the front end a matching list of `bool`s representing "has this field been updated" using javascript or jQuery. Then you can use that to determine what the user wants to update.

Comment: I also use graphql-go too, so I don't think SQL injection will effect

Comment: OK, but just be careful when dynamically creating SQL strings like this that you are positive that every piece of the string comes ONLY from inside your own code and you are in complete control. Then only pass the values to the Query function.

Comment: Tks for your advice @RayfenWindspear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just collect the non-nil values in a slice and then use that slice with `...` when executing the query.

```
var values []interface{}
for i := range m {
    if v := m[i]; v != "" && v != 0 && v != 0.0 && /* you're missing a condition here */{
        j++
        query = query + strings.ToLower(i) + "=$" + strconv.Itoa(j) + ","
        values = append(values, v)
    }
}

// ....

database.DB.QueryRow(query_string, values...)
```

Comment: Yes, i missed a condition there, btw, you solved my problem and save my day, tks you so much